# bootstrap columns stacking and not aligning in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html section that I can am trying to have three columns. Unfortunately, the divs are just stacking one under the other in the first column instead of making three separate columns.  I have tried looking at other posts, and spent some time trying to change rows and divs but nothing has worked.

```
<section class="about" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><h3>ABOUT</h3></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <p class ="about-title">ABOUT ME</p>
        <div class ="about-info">
          <p>sample paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <div>
          <img class="prof" src="css/img/prof.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <p>column three</p>
      </div>      
    </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Learn the grid system: One `.container` or `.container-fluid` can have multiple `.row` classes, which can each have any combination of `.col-x-y`, where `x` is `xs, sm, md or lg` and `y` is `1 - 12`, that adds up to `12`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't close your inner row divs. Each time you do that, you create a new row.

```
<section class="about" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><h3>ABOUT</h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <p class ="about-title">ABOUT ME</p>
        <div class ="about-info">
          <p>sample paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <div>
          <img class="prof" src="css/img/prof.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>      
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <p>column three</p>
      </div>      
    </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/F8serUuDVs)**

Answer (score 2):

You have your columns inside of `.row` divs, which makes separate rows.  Try removing them like this

```
<section class="about" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><h3>ABOUT</h3></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <p class ="about-title">ABOUT ME</p>
        <div class ="about-info">
          <p>sample paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <div>
          <img class="prof" src="css/img/prof.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>      
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <p>column three</p>
      </div>      
    </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```